# How to customize FoxitReader shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, foxit-reader

Recently, FoxitReader for Linux was officially introduced and I love it.

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/09/foxit-pdf-reader-sees-new-linux-release.html

However, somehow FoxitReader does not support shortcut keys for any comment tools. This is quite inconvenience for me, especially when I have to use the trackpad of my laptop to select the tool first.

So I would like to ask if is there any way to configure the shortcut keys of FoxitReader?

I do not see this feature in the preference of FoxitReader, so looking into the configuration files of FoxitReader in Linux could be a possible solution. But I am don't know how to do it.

Thanks for taking time reading my post!

Comment: Question is off-topic for stackoverflow, but anyway: In recent Foxit versions that have a ribbon UI, I can use `Alt`+`R` then `N` (not sure whether this varies depending on the locale). That is - in the Windows version that runs fine with Wine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure for linux but in window u can do this
Right click on toolbar at top

select customise quick access toolbar

then follow this

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

**Foxit version 2.4.1**

By default, they provide for highlight light text using `Ctrl+h` (Linux)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately this feature is not currently available. I'm sorry I can't give you a better answer. We (Foxit) are currently working on adding shortcut keys in future versions.

Comment: On Windows, I love the Foxit key shortcuts (U to underline, Shift+U to sqiggly underline, D to draw with pencil, A to make an arrow, T for typewriter, etc). Doing it with the mouse is much slower and really hurts the UX.

Comment: Please also consider adding vim navigation bindings.

Comment: It's nearly Apr. 2018 and still not available in Linux. I'm using Foxit 2.4.1.0609, which is the latest version right now. Please add it. Don't leave us hanging. Much appreciated!

Comment: It’s 2019 and Foxit still has no customizable keybinds. (;__; )

Comment: For the macOS version, there are predefined shortcuts but cannot be customized.

Comment: In macOS you can customize the keyboard shortcuts of any application in your System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

Comment: The lack of hotkey customization is compouned by having no support for "menu bar" accelerators (such as `Alt+F` for the "**F**ile" menu)

Comment: It’s 2020 and Foxit still has no customizable keybinds :c.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

Right-click the toolbar region -> Customize Toolbar -> choose the Keyboard tab -> choose the View menu -> change the shortcuts for Next Page and Previous Page.

See the shortcuts available in foxit.

Comment: This option seems to be not currectly available on Linux. There is only a Customize toolbar pane with no "Keyboard" tab

Answer (score 4):

For the newest version:

- Right click the ribbon under the "Home" section.
- Select customize ribbon.
- Navigate to the keyboard tab

I used this specifically to set the highlight tool. The section to find the highlight tool option is not intuitive so if your interested in setting the highlight shortcut just navigate to the comment section.

Comment: It seems to not be available on LInux

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to customized the shortcut on the Linux version. But for the windows version, Adiii has provided the solutions.

Two commonly used shortcut, which is already predefined in the Linux version is

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>: highlight

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>: note

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The FoxIt Linux version do not support keyboard customization, BUT we can easily use FoxIt (Windows) on Linux via Wine + PlayOnLinux.

I set it up on my Ubuntu 18 by:

1. Download the Foxit Windows version from https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/
2. Install via PlayOnLinux. (including adding a shortcut to the FoxitReader.exe)
3. Move the shortcut FoxitReader.desktop to the `.local/share/applications` and select any pdf file > `properties` > set the default application as FoxitReader.

This gives me the power of keyboard shortcut customization at a small price of slightly longer startup time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by user **[Adiii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3288890/adiii)** is sufficient above.
I would like to add,
the default option to highlight on foxit linux is ctrl + H
that option is occupied on windows for entering reading mode, since u would be highlighting more than entering the reading mode, assining alt+H to reading mode and assigning ctrl + H to highlight is the prudent choice.